# xs:restriction doesn't work in Spring WS

Tags: spring-ws

I defined my xsd this way (partial):

```
            <xs:element name="entityNo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
```

but when i send with SoapUI a string longer than 20 my Endpoint still receives it as if it was a valid input.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you using the schema to perform validation at runtime?  If so, show us how.

Comment: No, as far as i know. How do i achieve the above to reject messages that don't follow the restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, restriction works, i just had to add the PayloadValidatingInterceptor interceptor in spring-ws config file:

```
<sws:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
    <property name="schemas">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/schemasDef/first.xsd</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/schemasDef/second.xsd</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="validateRequest" value="true"/>
    <property name="validateResponse" value="true"/>
</bean>
</sws:interceptors>
```